# Visual Studio 2017 File Lock Problems, reverting to old File versions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I have been having problems with Visual Studio (2017), sometimes it doesn't recognize changes or suddenly reverts to an old version of a file, especially when updating resources like `Startup.cs` or other Compiled resources.

There have been several times where things have been working just fine and all of a sudden things explode, and after searching through the code I have found that one of the files that had been updated has gone back to a previous version. I am only working on local files, not using Git etc...

I have tried cleaning the entire Solution which sometimes fixes the issue, so maybe partly a cache problem?

Sometimes Compiler errors all of a sudden occur, even after cleaning the solution and the only way to fix it is to close VS, remove all `obj` and `bin` folders, restart then rebuild.

One thing that I have noticed is sometimes the `VBSCompiler.exe` will hang, even after shutting down VS and has to be manually killed. I have also noticed that using "Pinned" tabs or multiple windows over multiple monitors will make this problem allot worse, not to mention intermittent errors on opening VS.

This has lead me to think that some services (possibly IIS?) are locking the files, but VS starts a new service and opens a copy of the file, even after ensuring that the `VBSCompiler` hasn't hung, since the previous service still has the file lock it doesn't overwrite the file, but no Errors are generated, making me think that the file is current until both processes shut down. When the file is unlocked and opened again it is an old version.

I think this is supported by the last event, I removed a Project from the solution from VS, saved the solution, cleaned the solution, shut down VS, checked to see if any services like above were left running and deleted the Project files on the disk. I emptied the recycle bin but didn't let it quite finish before launching VS and received a error that file `%SugZuy/ClientApp` was locked and couldn't be removed, the Project had been removed from the Solution after restart, when I shut down VS and selected "Try Again" it was able to continue.

I have tried disabling backup files, tracking, always cleaning the entire solution before build, along with several suggestions I have found online regarding IIS and VSBCompiler problems, still with no luck. One last note, this is all on a brand new fresh install of both VS (2017 Community) and Windows 10 Pro, along with starting with a new Solution and Project (Using .Net Core Angular Template) in an attempt to fix this issue.

Comment: What your VS2017 version number?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 15.7.5

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017 Don't waste your time guessing. Contact Microsoft, and if possible, provide them more information to help reproduce the issue.

Comment: @LexLi I have already gone down that route in a round about sort of way, through my Dell Support Contract (worst decision I ever made). I have gotten absolutely nowhere, partly the reason for this Question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured out what is going on and ***maybe someone else can provide a better solution as I don't recommend this hack***.

I had installed NodeJS on my Development Machine along side VS 2017, I had removed the entire `$(VSInstallDir)\Web\External` entry from `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Web Package Management` thinking that VS would use the External NodeJS.

I then noticed that there was one `node.exe` running along side 2 other `Node.exe` processes, when I opened the file locations from the task manager, sure enough it was using the VS External Tools version of NodeJS along with NodeJS.

I think this was causing some conflicts and basically confusing some parts of VS, so when something hung up the compiler VS thought it shut down the correct process and started a new instance of NodeJS leaving the other one running that still had the file locked. So when all the processes were finally shut down, any changes that were made using the 2nd instances of NodeJS was basically ignored.

I tried to find every reference to NodeJS in Visual Studio, made sure the paths were in the right order in `Tools->Options...` along with searching for fixes but none worked, the only way I was able to "hide" the external tools from VS (even after reboot) was to rename `Node.exe` to `Node.exe.hide` in both

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\x86

I am sure there is a better way of fixing this, but I couldn't find it.